# Code Coverage for Django Project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, coverage.py

I installed coverage.py to measure the code coverage for my Django project. (As mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py)

But I currently have no test cases in my project. So, when I run coverage it says:

```
coverage run --source='.' manage.py test myapp
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

It clearly says that it ran 0 tests, but when I say

```
coverage report -m
```

It gives me a report with code coverage of 91%. Also it looks into only the models package that I have. It does not look into other packages that are there as part of my app.

So when I give

```
coverage run --source='.' manage.py test myapp/mypackage
```

It once again reports coverage only for models package.

How do I measure the code coverage for all packages of the app? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

```
myproject/
├── myapp
│   ├── models
│   ├── services
│   ├── statis
│   ├── templates
│   ├── utils
│   └── views
└── myproject
```

Report:

```
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------
manage                            11      2    82%   8-9
myapp/__init__                   0      0   100%   
myapp/admin                      1      1     0%   1
myapp/models/__init__            3      0   100%   
myapp/models/form/__init__      10      0   100%   
myapp/models/form/items         57      0   100%   
myapp/models/form/profile       14      0   100%   
myapp/models/form/sections      10      0   100%   
myapp/models/user/__init__      21      0   100%   
myapp/models/user/items         67      0   100%   
myapp/models/user/profile       13      1    92%   9
myapp/models/user/sections      60      0   100%   
myapp/tests                      1      0   100%   
myapp/urls                       7      7     0%   1-9
myproject/__init__                      0      0   100%   
myproject/manage                       11     11     0%   2-16
myproject/settings                     33      0   100%   
myproject/urls                          4      4     0%   1-6
myproject/wsgi                          4      4     0%   10-14
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                            327     30    91%
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with your directory structure?

Comment: The output of the coverage report command would also be helpful.

Comment: sounds like it runs and shows packages test cases which you are using

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing `__init__.py` files in some of your modules?

Comment: Ohh yess!! Thank you @JessamynSmith :) It works!! Bad that i missed it..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When modules are missing from code coverage, a good first step is to check for any missing `__init__.py` files.